# Error Python script in atom windows power shell

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting error when I am trying to execute a Python script in Atom.

> The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
>   script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
>   if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:7
>   + python <<<<  .\loading.py
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riiyz.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not added the path to Python, in your Environmental Path variable.
Try adding `C:\Python36\` and `C:\Python36\Scripts\` to the PATH

Answer (score 0):

Add this path to the 'Path' in system variable in environment variables.

C:\Users\%user profile%\AppData\Local\atom\bin

Make sure to use your "user profile" in the path. It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Open `atom`  through power shell
Should work